# Change property ConnectionString at runtime

Tags: c#, connection-string

is there any way to change the `ConnectionString` property that has application as scope at runtime?

Comment: yeah. `myApplication.ConnectionString = "new connection string"`. The other useful way is `myApplication.ConnectionString.Change("new conn string")` or even `myApp.Change(Items.ConnectionString, "new string")`.

Answer (score 2):

In this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61108264/7086678) you can use an connection string for each request. Just Change the `IUserService` to `IConnectionStringService`

```cs
public interface IConnectionStringService
{
    string GetConnectionString();
}
public class ConnectionStringService : IConnectionStringService
{
    public string GetConnectionString()
    {
        //read connection string from appSetting.json or anything
        return "";
    }
}
```