# User specific connection string in EntityFramework .net core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, architecture, entity-framework-core

We are developing a multitenant app using .net core and EntityFramework. There will be a single deployed instance of APIs but multiple DBS( one DB per user). So what's the best strategy change DB connection string as per-user context.

Comment: What kind of app? Desktop or web?

Comment: its an API @CaiusJard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the connection string in the `OnConfiguring` method of `DbContext`, by calling `UseSqlServer`, or whatever your database is. In this method, you need to have a reference to some service that will provide the user-specific connection. For this, IMO, the best way is to inject an `IHttpContextAccessor` through the `DbContext` class, and, inside `OnConfiguring`, use it to obtain the `HttpContext` and all the registered services. You must not forget to register `IHttpContextAccessor` by a call to `AddHttpContextAccessor`.
Sample code:

```
//MyContext
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext(DbContextOptions options, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor) : base(options)
    {
        this.HttpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    protected IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor { get; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder builder)
    {
        var context = this.HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
        var userService = context.RequestServices<IUserService>();
        var user = context.User.Identity.Name;
        var connectionString = userService.GetConnectionString(user);

        builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);

        base.OnConfiguring(builder);
    }
}


//Startup.ConfigureServices
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
services.AddDbContext<MyContext>();
```

Note that `IUserService` is just some service that you must implement that will return the connection string for the given user.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should implement something like is in this link
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dbcontext-creation

or like this example

```
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public interface IDbContextFactory 
{
    Task<TContext> Create<TContext>(int userId);
}

public class DbContextFactory : IDbContextFactory
{
    public DbContextFactory()
    {

    }

    public async Task<TContext> Create<TContext>(int userId)
        where TContext: DbContext, new()
    {
        //TODO: build connectionString using SqlConnectionStringBuilder and replace the values in []
        var connectionStringBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder("Application Name=SSCommitmentService;")
        {
            DataSource = $"tcp:[dbServer],1433",
            InitialCatalog = "[catalog]",
            UserID = "[sqlUserid]",
            Password = "[sqlPassword]"
        };
        var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<TContext>();
        //TODO: configure the DbContextOptions to use the Provider (Sql, MySql, etc)
        options.UseSqlServer(connectionStringBuilder.ConnectionString);
        //TODO: instantiate the required dbcontext
        var dbContext = new TContext(options.Options);
        return dbContext;
    }
}
```