# Getting user information from token in ASP.NET Core Web API During AddDbContext

Tags: c#, oracle, .net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-webapi

We are currently migrating an app from WCF to ASP.NET Core Web API.

When we register the services, we are using `AddDbContext` to register the database provider on a per call basis. However, when we construct the connection string we need the connecting user id (from the token) so we can set a proxy user in the connection string, we can then journal the actual user ID on various sensitive transactions.

Is there anyway I can get access to the token at this point, and if not are there any suggestions on where we should set the connection string?

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ADatabaseContext>(options =>    
{
    options.UseOracle(need user id from token here);

    if (Debugger.IsAttached)
    {
        options.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
    }
});
```

Comment: this might be related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61107857/user-specific-connection-string-in-entityframework-net-core

Comment: thanks @jeb it is, and the answer was just what I was looking for